# jQuery Tree Plugin supporting CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery tree plugin which will allow me to perform CRUD operations on the tree hopefully through a Modal dialog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.jstree.com/) is one of the best. Create, remove, delete and move operations are easy with [CRRM plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm).